# Which js framework can take initial data from DOM?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm trying to find any modern MVVM / MVC / js framework which automatically binds initial data from server rendered HTML.

Now I need to load data twice for every page: 1 in html (important for SEO), 2 for view model initializing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want render the page at first request with data, but other interactions should run in javascript app.

You may find [angular-universal](https://universal.angular.io/) interesting.It renders same angular app at server side but i dont know for the rest really